# ajax call on keyup()

Tags: jquery, ajax, keyup

I have an issue: 
if someone is typing in field, this should make the text field for all other user as readonly and show msg like "someone is typing right now".

```
<div id="msg"></div>
<input type="text" name="field" id="field" />

$("#field").keyup(function (){
    var isTyping = $('#field').val();
    var data = 'result=' + isTyping;
    var msg = $('#msg');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "includes/control.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function(){  
           msg.html(html);
        }
    });
});
```

And this is control.php:

```
if($_POST['result']){
    echo "someone is typing";
}
```

This work like a sharm for click() method but not for keyup().

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your `$("#field").keyup()` function located within your `document.ready` callback?

Comment: yep it is within document.ready

Answer (score 3):

Strange that you are sending an ajax request whenever user types but change:

```
success: function(){  
    msg.html(html);
}
```

to

```
success: function(html){  
    msg.html(html);
}
```

since your `html` wasn't defined as ajax response.

Comment: The problem was with the `.click()` callback vs. the `keyup()` callback.  He did say that it works with a mouse click.  While this **is helpful** - I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: @Lix: The obvious issue with the code he has **posted** is what i can see. Let's *wait* and see.

Comment: Why it is strange? It's just a prevent method to stop user from typing if someone other is allready by typing. anyway it was not a solution.

Comment: @MadDorris: *Not strange for you or your requirement* but you should explian more clearly to get better answers. Saying `it was not a solution` doesn't help any of us here too :)

Comment: I have to do something like chat. The only difference is that users can not write at the same time. Because of this i will show to other users that someone is allready in field. It is basicly function. The rest (restriction on time and IP) will be wroten in PHP.